# map behaves strangely on DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I'm seeing a strange behaviour on the map function when applied to a DatetimeIndex, where the first element that is mapped is the whole index, and then each element is processed individually (as expected).

Here's a way to reproduce the issue
(Have tried it on pandas 0.22.0, 0.23.0 and 0.24.0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.random.randn(3,1),
                  index = pd.DatetimeIndex(
                              start='2018-05-03', 
                              periods = 3, 
                              freq ='D'))

df.index.map(lambda x: print(x))
```

yields:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2018-05-03', '2018-05-04', '2018-05-05'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
2018-05-03 00:00:00
2018-05-04 00:00:00
2018-05-05 00:00:00
Index([None, None, None], dtype='object')
```

---

EDIT: The very first line that the print is producing is what I find odd. If I use a RangeIndex this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Surprising print behaviour**

This unusual behaviour only affects a `DatetimeIndex` and not a `Series`. So to fix the bug, wrap your index in `pd.Series()` before mapping the lambda function:

```
pd.Series(df.index).map(lambda x: print(x))
```

Alternatively you can use the `.to_series()` method:

```
df.index.to_series().map(lambda x: print(x))
```

Note the return values of the `pd.Series()` version will be numerically indexed, while the return values of the `.to_series()` version will be datetime indexed.

**Is this a bug?**

`Index.map()`, like `Series.map()`, returns a Series containing the return values of your lambda function.

In this case, `print()` just returns `None`, so you are correctly getting an Index Series of `None` values. The print behaviour is inconsistent with other types of pandas Indexes and Series, but this is an unusual application.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.random.randn(3,1),
              index = pd.DatetimeIndex(
                          start='2018-05-03', 
                          periods = 3, 
                          freq ='D'))

example = df.index.map(lambda x: print(x))
# DatetimeIndex(['2018-05-03', '2018-05-04', '2018-05-05'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
# 2018-05-03 00:00:00
# 2018-05-04 00:00:00
# 2018-05-05 00:00:00
print(example)
# Index([None, None, None], dtype='object')
```

As you can see, there's nothing wrong with the return value. Or for a clearer example, where we add one day to each item:

```
example2 = df.index.map(lambda x: x + 1)
print(example2)
# DatetimeIndex(['2018-05-04', '2018-05-05', '2018-05-06'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

So the print behaviour is inconsistent with similar classes in pandas, but the return values are correct.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. I'm actually referring to the lines that are being printed before the return value (i.e. what the lambda function prints)... why is it printing that first line with the whole index and then each item of the index? If I use a RangeIndex this doesn't happen.

Comment: No worries - yes, I understood that, but was just pointing out that the substantive behaviour is correct. As I said, it's a strange combination of `.map()` and `print()`. What would be the use case where this print behaviour causes a problem?

Comment: I imagined this was not a common pratice, and you're right. I'm only using the print statement for debugging purposes, as I started noticing this behaviour on a much complex lambda function that is being applied on each timestamp to find the closest item on another dataframe, however it fails since it appears to me that the first record that it receives is actually the whole index.

Comment: You're right, it is strange - am trying to find the relevant source code so I can write a proper explanation of the bug. As you say, only DatetimeIndex is affected - not a DateTime Series and not a range Index. I'm struggling to imagine an example where your debugging pattern cannot be changed for something else, though? For example, assigning the map to a new Series, and then iteratively printing out the contents of that Series?

Comment: I have now updated my answer with a fix for your problem - let me know if that solves it.

Comment: thanks @ajrwhite... this gets rid of that first print statement, and while I still wonder why DatetimeIndex behaves that way, I'll mark your answer as completed for all the work you've put in helping me.

Comment: I get this exact behaviour on an actual `Series` of timestamps in a Pandas DataFrame when using `map()` - very strange.